# Run cookies script only if checkbox contains class on page load

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a cookies consent where I have categories like necessary cookies, adveritsing cookies, functional cookies etc.

What do I need to do is to run scripts once checkbox for category has class `"jozo"` (in this case its checked) on page load. But my script does not work.

On my HTML side its working like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="wt-cli-checkbox-advertisement" class="cli-user-preference-checkbox jozo" data-id="checkbox-advertisement" checked="checked">
```

Js side

```
if ($ ('input#wt-cli-checkbox-advertisement').hasClass('jozo')){
                $(document).ready(function() {
                        Facebook.loadPixel();
                        Analytics.loadPixel();
                        GAds.loadPixel(); 
                        });
                }
```

I need to also do that if it does not contain class `"jozo"` then run following script:

```
 Facebook.disable();
 Analytics.disable();
 GAds.disable();
```

This needs to be recognised on each page load. Now my scrips are not runing. They only run if I add this but then users can not turn them of in accord of the GDPR law.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Facebook.loadPixel();
    Analytics.loadPixel();
    GAds.loadPixel(); 
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does happen? Are you getting an error in the console?

Comment: No no error there, but it does not run the analytics, facebook and adwords scripts on page load.

Comment: You running your script after the document is ready? Maybe the checkbox not exists.

Comment: There is a syntax problem. in your condition. there is a space between $ and first parenthasis

Comment: @Alaeddine same problem after fixing syntax. Btw thank you for showing me this.

Comment: @amiad checkbox is located in a popup in cookie bar

Comment: I think you should put your condition inside the document ready. if the class exists then loadPixles

Comment: Could you please try to add answers bellow so I may check what you mean? :) thx guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the checkbox loading after your script running. Convert it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('input#wt-cli-checkbox-advertisement').hasClass('jozo')){
       Facebook.loadPixel();
       Analytics.loadPixel();
       GAds.loadPixel(); 
   }
   else {
       Facebook.disable();
       Analytics.disable();
       GAds.disable();
   }
});
```

Comment: This seems to work, and how about the part number 2 of the question. If it does not contains class jozo then I need to run .disable();

Comment: I added `else`.